# Optimize Javascript Method to fill or empty an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, optimization

I'm wondering if there is a better way to add/remove checkbox values to an array. Sadly i can't use ECMAScript 5 `indexOf()` as i need to support IE8/7.

Here is a working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/puyQr/

What this Method does is:

```
/**
 * If a user clicks onto the checkbox, the value of the value attribute is
 * only added to the array when the value not yet exists. However, if
 * the value already exists, the value is removed.
 */

var values = [];
jQuery(':checkbox').on('click', function(){     
    var index = jQuery.inArray(this.value, values);
    if(index === -1) {
        values.push(this.value);
    } else {
        values.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: You could keep an object as a map and add/remove the checkbox names (or values I guess). It'd be faster, though unless you've got hundreds of checkboxes it'd make no real difference.

Comment: MDN has code to [support indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in those browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way to get values from checkboxes:

```
var values = jQuery(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eRqCJ/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use an object literal.

```
var values = {};
jQuery(':checkbox').on('click', function () {     
    if (this.value in values && values[this.value] === 1) {
        values[this.value] = 0;
    } else {
        values[this.value] = 1;
    }
});
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kLeWc/).

If you want it as an *Array* later, converting it is a simple matter, using [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and checking the *value* is `1` before keeping the *key*.